# Laravel 6.0.3 Not Loading Key Resources App.js or App.css 404 Not Found

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

To setup my project I ran:

```
laravel new cms
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui:auth
php artisan migrate
```

However, when I go to http://cms.test/login I am shown the login page:

[image]

And get two 404 errors for missing resources:

```
http://cms.test/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
http://cms.test/css/app.css
```

What could be the reason for these missing files?

My public directory is empty aside from .htaccess, favicon.ico,  index.php and robot.txt files, is that normal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My setup was a little wrong, I mostly forgetting to run npm install and npm run dev command that is required to compile the app.js and app.css files.

Correct setup command sequence was:

```
laravel new cms
cd cms
php artisan migrate
composer require laravel/ui
npm install
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

The app.css and app.js were missing from a new app.  The proper steps had been run as are noted in Jack Robson's answer above.  I reran the last two steps:

```
    php artisan ui vue --auth
    npm install && npm run dev
```

And it generated the app.css and app.js - all good now.

No idea what had gone wrong in the initial install.

Answer (score 1):

The below command did the trick for me.

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was:
that when configuring the
Virtual Host in Apache wrote the path to the folder incorrectly:

    **DocumentRoot "D: \ LARAVEL \ instagrmalaravel \ public"**
...

when on host it was:
**127.0.0.1 instagramlaravel.local,**

change: **instagrmalaravel to: instagramlaravel.**

And everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the files are missing is you forgot to run the build process that generates the files. The last command `npm run dev` does this. Having the 2 commands paired (`npm install && npm run dev`) in the docs seems to be catching a lot of people out.